# OAuth vs OpenID: confused about when to use one of these and why

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization, openid

So these days I was reading about `OpenID` and `OAuth2`. I've seen some questions ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33702826/oauth-authorization-vs-authentication) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19293793/oauth-2-access-token-vs-openid-connect-id-token)), but from what I've read you can use `OAuth` and for authentication, not just for authorization. On the second question, I've read this:

> If you have an account (with some private resources) in a website, you
>   can log in with username/password couple. If an application would like
>   to get some private resources, and if you don't want to give them your
>   username/password, use OAuth.
>
> But if you want to log in into multiple websites with a unique
>   account, use OpenID.

This raised more confusions (Dominick Baier said in one of his presentation that if you haven't heared about `OAuth2` these years, you were living in a cave for the last years, so it seems this was my case): If I have many webservices (API's) and if I have an `STS` service to request tokens for all the API's then I am using `OpenID`? Is `OAuth` is not scalable to extend the authorization to multiple sites using a single STS service?

When you try to explain me, please consider that I haven't implemented an authentication or authorization process before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right: lot of authorization servers based on OAuth2 provides a way to authenticate. But OAuth2 is not designed for that purpose.
In an OAuth2 context, the client has just an access token to retrieve/manage resources on a resource server. It knows nothing about the resource owner.

That is why the OpenID Connect protocol has been created. It works on top of the OAuth2 Framework protocol and allows the client to get information about the resource owner.

I recommend you to look at [this very interesting talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BdKmZ7mPNns) (start at 4:44). This video helped me a lot to understand the purpose of each token. I hope it will help you too.

Comment: For SPA, it looks like it uses 'id_token' in place of 'access_token'. Is it true that 'id_token' is taking over in this special case for SPA? One reason is that, SPA XHR cannot talk to OAuth Token Endpoint because of CORS Policy.

Comment: The `id_token` gives information about the user (name, id, address, phone...). The `access_token` gives access to the data owned by the user and managed by a resource server. A SPA can use both token or only one. If the SPA cannot talk to a token endpoint because of CORS policy, this is because the there is something wrong with the endpoint configuration.

Comment: Oh, thanks! I have discussed about it in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55827056/oauth-2-0-spa-how-does-id-token-disguise-as-an-access-token-for-accessing-re/55827801?noredirect=1#comment98321526_55827801

Comment: Now I understood that SPA acquires id_token for authentication and acquires access_token by calling Az Token Endpoint from iFrame for calling external Web APIs.